# Why does request fail when filtered by st_distance in presto?

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I try to filter by `st_distance` in my request, but presto failed saying that my latitude is not in the range (-90,90), without filter request it was working:

```
presto> SELECT id, id_type, lat, lon, ST_Distance(to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(lat, lon)), to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(59.988658, 30.200408))) 
       FROM geo.geo_data 
       WHERE ST_Distance(to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(lat, lon)), to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(59.988658, 30.200408))) < 500.0;

Query failed: Latitude must be between -90 and 90
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some incorrect data in your table. You can find it conveniently with using [`try()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try).

```
SELECT * 
FROM geo.geo_data
WHERE try(ST_Point(lat, lon)) IS NULL
```